# Selecting rows that has exactly same data as other table

Tags: oracle, join, plsql

I have these tables:
**Products**, **Articles**, **Product_Articles**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Lets say, product_ids are: **p1** , **p2** article_ids are: **a1** , **a2** , **a3** 
product_articles is:

- **(p1,a1)**
- **(p1,a2)**
- **(p2,a1)**
- **(p2,a1)**
- **(p2,a2)**
- **(p2,a3)**

How to query for product_id, which has only a1,a2, nothing less, nothing more?

Comment: Oracle Database PL/SQL

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** Try

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM products p JOIN 
(
  SELECT product_id
    FROM product_articles
   GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN article_id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     AND SUM(CASE WHEN article_id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
) q ON p.product_id = q.product_id
```

or

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM products p JOIN 
(
  SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) a_count
    FROM product_articles
   WHERE article_id IN (1, 2)
   GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) a ON p.product_id = a.product_id JOIN
(
  SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) total_count
    FROM product_articles
   GROUP BY product_id
) b ON p.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE a.a_count = b.total_count
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5947/3)** demo for both queries

Comment: I read 'nothing less' as meaning a product has to have both `a1` and `a2` (might be wrong of course); this [will find products with either](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b67e7/1). [Counting the distinct articles](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b67e7/2) would 'fix' that, there might be better ways...

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT COUNT(article_id) FROM articles WHERE article_id in (1,2))

Should be fine?

Comment: @AlexPoole In OP's case (product_id, article_id) is a PK thus UNIQE. Therefore there can't be duplicates. So IMHO the query does exactly as asked.

Comment: Nothing, I like it, but on faculty we didn't learn CASE, so they do not allow it

Comment: @JovanMeshkov See updated answer for another approach with joins

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32818/discussion-between-jovan-meshkov-and-peterm)

Comment: @JovanMeshkov This case is already covered by both queries. See updated answer and updated sqlfiddle

Comment: @JovanMeshkov Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I advocate using aggregation with a `having` clause for the logic, because this is the most general way to express the relationships.

The idea is that you can count the appearance of the articles within a product (in this case) in a way similar to using a `where` statement.  The code is a bit more complex, but it offers flexibility.  In your case, this would be:

```
select pa.product_id
from product_articles pa
group by pa.product_id
having sum(case when pa.article_id = 'a1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when pa.article_id = 'a2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when pa.article_id not in ('a1', 'a2') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The first two clauses count the appearance of the two articles, making sure that there is at least one occurrence of each.  The last counts the number of rows without those two articles, making sure there are none.

You can see how this easily generalizes to more articles.  Or to queries where you have "a1" and "a2" but not "a3".  Or where you have three of four of specific articles, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done entirely using relational joins, as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pa1.PRODUCT_ID
  FROM PRODUCT_ARTICLES pa1
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT_ARTICLES pa2
    ON (pa2.PRODUCT_ID = pa1.PRODUCT_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                     FROM PRODUCT_ARTICLES
                     WHERE ARTICLE_ID NOT IN (1, 2)) pa3
    ON (pa3.PRODUCT_ID = pa1.PRODUCT_ID)
  WHERE pa1.ARTICLE_ID = 1 AND
        pa2.ARTICLE_ID = 2 AND
        pa3.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87f31/3).

The inner join looks for products associated with the articles we care about (articles 1 and 2 - produces product 1 and 2).  The left outer looks for products associated with articles we don't care about (anything article *except* 1 and 2) and then only accepts products which don't have any unwanted articles (i.e. `pa3.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL`, indicating that no row from `pa3` was joined in).